# confusion with base64 class methods usage

Tags: ruby

Could anyone help me here to understand when we need to consider the
below 4 methods:

```
strict_decode64(str)
strict_encode64(bin)
urlsafe_encode64(bin)
urlsafe_decode64(str)
```

From the doc also I didn't get any examples. So examples with
explanation might be helpful for me to understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is unclear in [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html)?

Comment: docs is lacking examples. Only few words there. Thus couldn't understand the usage of it. what strictness it actually means, what it can do which the normal `encoding` and `decoding` can't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An example of usage would be:

```
require "base64"
Base64.strict_encode64('Stuff to be encoded')
Base64.strict_decode64("U3R1ZmYgdG8gYmUgZW5jb2RlZA==")
```

Strict means that white spaces / CR/LF are rejected at decode and CR/LF are not added at encode.

Note that if the folowing is accepted:

```
Base64.decode64("U3R1ZmYgdG8gYmUgZW5jb2RlZA==\n")
```

with ***strict*** the above is not accepted because of the trailing `\n` (linefeed) and the following line will throw `ArgumentError: invalid base64` exception:

```
Base64.strict_decode64("U3R1ZmYgdG8gYmUgZW5jb2RlZA==\n")
```

So strict accepts/expects only alphanumeric characters at decode and returns only alphanumeric at encode.

Please try the following and see how one encodes wraps the lines every 60 characters with `'\n'` (linefeed) and the ***strict*** doesn't:

```
print Base64.encode64('I will not use spaces and new lines. I will not use spaces and new lines. I will not use spaces and new lines. I will not use spaces and new lines.I will not use spaces and new lines.')


print Base64.strict_encode64('I will not use spaces and new lines. I will not use spaces and new lines. I will not use spaces and new lines. I will not use spaces and new lines.I will not use spaces and new lines.')
```

Comment: @iAmRubuuu added an example hope it helps

Comment: @iAmRubuuu both of the above examples are for *str*, *bin* means that other binary representation are used escaped but it is still a string ex: `Base64.strict_encode64("\xaa\xab\xac\xad")`, `Base64.strict_decode64("\x553R1ZmYgdG8gYmUgZW5jb2RlZA==")` notice the `U` in the example from answer is replaced by `\x55`

Answer (score 5):

The `_encode` and `_decode` do opposite things: the first one converts a normal string into an encoded string, and the second one converts an encoded string into a normal string.

```
str = "Hello!"
str == decode64(encode64(str)) # This is true
```

The difference between `strict_` and `urlsafe_` is the characters that will be used inside the encoded string. When you need to pass your string inside a URL, all characters are not allowed (like `/` for instance, because it has a special meaning in URLs) so you should use the `urlsafe_` version.